# WPF Coordinates of intersection from two Line objects

Tags: c#, wpf, math

I have two Line objects in C# WPF, and I'm trying to construct a method to work out the coordinates at which the lines intersect (if at all). After giving myself a headache reminding myself of high school maths to do this, I can't work out how to map it into programming format - anyone know how to do this?

Thanks very much,
Becky

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose your line objects are made up of two points. What you should do is get the equations of both lines.

Then you should solve the following equation:

equation-line1 = equation-line2

Calculate slope of a line:

```
    float _slope = 1e+10;
    if ((p2.x - p1.x) != 0)
        _slope = (p2.y - p1.y) / (p2.x - p1.x);
```

p1 = Point 1 of your line
p2 = Point 2 of your line

Equation of a line:

y = ax + b

a = the slope you calculated
b = the intersect

Solving the equation:

```
    a1 = p1.y - b1 * p1.x;
    a2 = q1.y - b2 * q1.x;

    x = (a1 - a2) / (b2 - b1);
    y = a2 + b2 * x;
```

vars:

- b1 = slope line 1
- b2 = slop line 2
- q1 = point 1 of your 2nd line

So, x and y are the coordinates of the point where the two lines intersect

Comment: Its how to do that programmatically that I can't seem to work out.

Comment: I got that far, it was the line-equation1 = line-equation2 that I can't figure out, as surely the algebra will change each time?

Comment: Consider:

float slope = float.MaxValue;

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a gee-whiz answer than a practical one, because if all you are doing is intersecting two lines it is very slow.  However I thought it was worth a mention.

WPF has the ability to intersect any two shape outlines, including two lines, and tell you the location of the intersection.

Here is the general technique for intersecting two outlines (the edges, not the fill area):

```
var shape1 = ...;
var shape2 = ...;

var thinPen = new Pen(Brush.Transparent, 0.001);

var geometry1 = shape1.RenderedGeometry.GetWidenedPathGeometry(thinPen);
var geometry2 = shape2.RenderedGeometry.GetWidenedPathGeometry(thinPen);

var combined = Geometry.Combine(
                 geometry1,
                 geometry2,
                 GeometryCombineMode.Intersect,
                 shape2.TransformToVisual(shape1));

var bounds = combined.GetRenderBounds(thinPen);
```

If the shapes are known to have the same position the `shape2.TransformToVisual(shape1)` in the call to `Geometry.Combine` can be replaced with `null`.

This technique can be very useful, if, for example, you need to intersect a line with an arbitrary curve.

Answer (score 0):

How to find intersection of two lines/segments/ray with rectangle

```
public class LineEquation{
    public LineEquation(Point start, Point end){
        Start = start;
        End = end;

        IsVertical = Math.Abs(End.X - start.X) < 0.00001f;
        M = (End.Y - Start.Y)/(End.X - Start.X);
        A = -M;
        B = 1;
        C = Start.Y - M*Start.X;
    }

    public bool IsVertical { get; private set; }

    public double M { get; private set; }

    public Point Start { get; private set; }
    public Point End { get; private set; }

    public double A { get; private set; }
    public double B { get; private set; }
    public double C { get; private set; }

    public bool IntersectsWithLine(LineEquation otherLine, out Point intersectionPoint){
        intersectionPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        if (IsVertical && otherLine.IsVertical)
            return false;
        if (IsVertical || otherLine.IsVertical){
            intersectionPoint = GetIntersectionPointIfOneIsVertical(otherLine, this);
            return true;
        }
        double delta = A*otherLine.B - otherLine.A*B;
        bool hasIntersection = Math.Abs(delta - 0) > 0.0001f;
        if (hasIntersection){
            double x = (otherLine.B*C - B*otherLine.C)/delta;
            double y = (A*otherLine.C - otherLine.A*C)/delta;
            intersectionPoint = new Point(x, y);
        }
        return hasIntersection;
    }

    private static Point GetIntersectionPointIfOneIsVertical(LineEquation line1, LineEquation line2){
        LineEquation verticalLine = line2.IsVertical ? line2 : line1;
        LineEquation nonVerticalLine = line2.IsVertical ? line1 : line2;

        double y = (verticalLine.Start.X - nonVerticalLine.Start.X)*
                   (nonVerticalLine.End.Y - nonVerticalLine.Start.Y)/
                   ((nonVerticalLine.End.X - nonVerticalLine.Start.X)) +
                   nonVerticalLine.Start.Y;
        double x = line1.IsVertical ? line1.Start.X : line2.Start.X;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    public bool IntersectWithSegementOfLine(LineEquation otherLine, out Point intersectionPoint){
        bool hasIntersection = IntersectsWithLine(otherLine, out intersectionPoint);
        if (hasIntersection)
            return intersectionPoint.IsBetweenTwoPoints(otherLine.Start, otherLine.End);
        return false;
    }

    public bool GetIntersectionLineForRay(Rect rectangle, out LineEquation intersectionLine){
        if (Start == End){
            intersectionLine = null;
            return false;
        }
        IEnumerable<LineEquation> lines = rectangle.GetLinesForRectangle();
        intersectionLine = new LineEquation(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0));
        var intersections = new Dictionary<LineEquation, Point>();
        foreach (LineEquation equation in lines){
            Point point;
            if (IntersectWithSegementOfLine(equation, out point))
                intersections[equation] = point;
        }
        if (!intersections.Any())
            return false;

        var intersectionPoints = new SortedDictionary<double, Point>();
        foreach (var intersection in intersections){
            if (End.IsBetweenTwoPoints(Start, intersection.Value) ||
                intersection.Value.IsBetweenTwoPoints(Start, End)){
                double distanceToPoint = Start.DistanceToPoint(intersection.Value);
                intersectionPoints[distanceToPoint] = intersection.Value;
            }
        }
        if (intersectionPoints.Count == 1){
            Point endPoint = intersectionPoints.First().Value;
            intersectionLine = new LineEquation(Start, endPoint);
            return true;
        }

        if (intersectionPoints.Count == 2){
            Point start = intersectionPoints.First().Value;
            Point end = intersectionPoints.Last().Value;
            intersectionLine = new LineEquation(start, end);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override string ToString(){
        return "[" + Start + "], [" + End + "]";
    }
}
```

full sample is described [here](http://www.artiom.pro/2013/06/c-find-intersections-of-two-line-by.html)